# Visual guidelines across multiple products

Tags: tutorial, interface-design, identity

Where can I find resources on how to create a visual guideline across multiple products, eg. apps.

Example; If a company wants to do 20 apps, and they should have a visual guideline across all 20 apps. The functionality ect in each app is completely different, but the style is the same.

Where can I find resources on how to get started with creating such a guideline? What does it take and whats the does and don'ts?

Comment: Are you referring to consistency between brands?

Comment: Yes, that would be one way to put it. I know the obvious thing is to create a Visual Guideline, with fonts, colors, logos ect. But it doesn't end there, since its all made interactive. 
Different products/apps, with different functionality and hereby UX and UIs. Whats the best practice on keeping a consistency in a scenario like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual or branding guidelines is a broad term that could describe any number of things; the customary ambiguity of GD terms; yet I've noticed that in most cases they are a necessary measure to ensure third parties apply your branding correctly.

What you're talking about is more a consistent similarity and feel between the apps which I think can be better categorised as creating a theme or template.

A uniform feel across digital content is often best achieved through consistency of layout elements **positioning and behaviour** as is evident in the Stack Exchange network of sites.

Without knowing what your apps are about or how un/connected they are to each other, I would advise you to focus on creating the consistent layout elements that will exist in all of the apps.

Further to this, I think that the fewer consistent elements you have, the more you should try to make the ones that you do have stand out.

For example, if the only consistent element is the navigation, make that navigation memorable and a visual focal point.

On the flip side, if you have 8 consistent elements you can relax and tone it down a bit, as simply using the same layout will go a long way towards achieving a similar feel.